# Xamarin Refit Deserelizar Array al consumir Rest API Service

Tags: c#, xamarin, http-get

`introducir el código aquí`Hola amigos estoy aprendiendo a usar *Refit* con *Xamarin forms* , pero tengo problemas para deseralizar un array[] de un servicio que tengo, entonces estoy tratando de hacerlo y me da este error. Este error se me hace muy comun al poder deserealizar un array con una lista, pero al estar usando Refit no se si haya otra implentacion o donde debo usarla. Alguien pdoria orientarme de como hacer esto bien?

Error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'miproyecto.Models.AccountList' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Interfaz

```
public interface IJMServices
{        
    [Get("/t/client-by-mail/:{email}")]
    Task<AccountList> GetAccount(string email);         
}
```

Este es el metodo dentro de mi view model

```
 async void GetStudents(string email)
    {
        var accountData = RestService.For<IJMServices>("https://miapi.herokuapp.com");
        try
        {
            var response = await accountData.GetAccount("xxxx@gmail.com");
            var resp = response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }             
    }
```

Este es mi model

```
    public class AccountList
{
    public IList<AccountData> AccList { get; set; }
}

public class AccountData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id_cartera")]
    public long IdCartera { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public object Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("escolaridad")]
    public string Escolaridad { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ocupacion")]
    public string Ocupacion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mail")]
    public string Mail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("oficina")]
    public string Oficina { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parentesco")]
    public string Parentesco { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trabajo")]
    public string Trabajo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("estado")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Esta es mi json

```
[{"id":212,"id_cartera":0,"created_at":"2020-07-02T16:08:26.000Z","status":null,"name":"Gabriela Montoya León ","escolaridad":"lincenciatura","ocupacion":"Administradora","mail":"g2919@hotmail.com","phone":"9615798250","oficina":"678686","parentesco":"Madre","trabajo":"Centro de Estudios en Artes Culinarios","estado":"Vigente"}]
```

Comment: y donde haces la deserializacion? lo unico que veo que deberias cambiar, es recibir un arreglo en lugar de List

Comment: hola @RamiroBarone , efectivamente eso hice, si gustas puedes postear la respuesta y te la doy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi solucion fue cambiar `List` por `Array []` ya que aunque a la vista humana del json parece que ese array uno lo puedo convertir a un List, si falla es porque hay que cambiarlo.

Solo debes cambiar `List` por `Array` en tu modelo.

```
public class AccountList
{
    public AccountData[] AccList { get; set; }
}
```

Edición de segunda solución:

```
 [Get("/t/client-by-mail/{email}")] 
 Task<List<AccountData>> GetAccount(string email);
```

Comment: mira mi solucion fue agregar el list desde la intergaz entonces me quedo algo asi  ' [Get("/t/client-by-mail/{email}")]
        Task<List<AccountData>> GetAccount(string email); '  dime por favor que piensas

Comment: Si te funciono, esta bien, use una sola vez Refit, y puede funcionar diferente la deserializacion de forma automatica. Agrego tu solucion a la respuesta para que quede asentada para otra persona.